# How to detect moved lines of code in gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

In Gerrit's review UI, is there any extension or way to identify lines of code that were moved?  Currently everything appears to be a normal added/removed line.

This is a feature I sorely miss from Reviewboard and even `git --color-moved`.